# Openfire and LDAP issues

Tags: openfire

Thanks in advance for the help.

Has anyone see this issue with openfire?

Currently I use Openfire Fedora with Auth using windows 2003 and also use mysql for the database. When I bring up two clients and talk to each other the time is slow between messages. Sometimes it can take between 5-15 minutes for something sent to get to the person (this is with only two people on the openfire server). I ran a tcp dump using port 389 and see that the machine is running thousands of queries against ldap. When i plug it into wireshark I notice that it is transferring the entire contact list or checking on the status of the entire contact list ?

When I run debug on openfire itself I am presented with only this small message in the log:

```
2010.06.08 07:01:17  LdapManager: Starting LDAP search...
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: ... search finished
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: Creating a DirContext in LdapManager.getContext()...
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: Created hashtable with context values, attempting to create context...
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: ... context created successfully, returning.
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: Trying to find a groups's DN based on it's groupname. cn: Spark agents CLT, Base DN: OU="Hidden",DC="Hidden",DC="net"...
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: Creating a DirContext in LdapManager.getContext()...
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: Created hashtable with context values, attempting to create context...
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: ... context created successfully, returning.
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: Starting LDAP search...
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: ... search finished
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: Trying to find a groups's DN based on it's groupname. cn: Spark agents CLT, Base DN: OU="Hidden",DC="Hidden",DC="net"...
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: Creating a DirContext in LdapManager.getContext()...
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: Created hashtable with context values, attempting to create context...
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: ... context created successfully, returning.
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: Starting LDAP search...
2010.06.08 07:01:17 LdapManager: ... search finished
```

I thought this was a configuration on my end and started to look into the cache settings on the openfire webpages. I tweaked the settings as recommend by the pages and still get the same issues. I doesnt seem to cache the contact list or this might be a feature never fixed or implemented.

Has anyone gone through this before ? I have searched online and I see others have great experience with openfire with no issues like I have, or is it because noone checked the queries ?

For the time being I created a new Domain Controller and moved openfire to that computer so it can run local queries. This seems to help reduce the speed alot, but when I run the server performance manager tool I see that with two people only using that openfire server I run 593.7 request per second.

Thanks for your help, if I didnt provide enough data please let me know what you need and I can find it.

Adding other information from conversation:
I am still double checking my settings, but they seem correct. When I do a wireshark I notice though that it sends the entire contact list as the query, I am assuming that it caches under the roster list. However some of the cashe fields dont see to be used even though they are set.

I looked at the link you sent and I had added that to my openfire earlier hoping that would fix it, still the same issue.

Has anyone ever done a server performance manager to see if you have the same issue as me ? Or a tcpdump. When I run openfire and Ldap on the same server it seems to only take 2-5 seconds with only two people on it instead of the 2-5 minutes it took not having it on. Last check the performance manager says 600 per second.

My main though is its just not caching, but I am not sure if this is right.

Thanks for the great feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's not finding ldap at all. From the log dump, it looks like the context build may be coming up empty and the whole process starts over again.

I would take another hard look at your config.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/ldap-guide.html

Base DN: OU="Hidden",DC="Hidden",DC="net" //is this valid for your setup??

Comment: Sorry about that. The Hidden is my domain name, I just removed the actual name and placed hidden in its place. I am relooking at my ldap configuration, however my entire list is all active directory so if it didnt work would I be able to login using a AD account ?

Comment: I was thinking you probably did that. The link I provided has a section dealing with AD. I would check each setting carefully. Are you connecting using an admin DN?

Comment: I wonder if this would be of any help. The log files near the end of the page seem similar to what you're seeing: http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/message/201922

Comment: WOuldnt let me add a comment so I attached more information above.

Thanks

Comment: Here is some new information: 
When I remove the packet filter rules I go from:
LdapRequest Responce time: 0  Queries : 1,714.4  CPU% 9.5 
LdapRequest Responce time: 0  Queries:  12.6     CPU% 0.1 
Has anyone seen this issue with this plugin before ?